# JavaFX Calling a Method from Another Controller

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, controller, fxml

I have a `TabPane` with multiple Tabs, each Tab has its own fxml file and controller. Now I'm trying to access a method (inside of controller A) from controller B.

e.g. whenever the `handleAddClick()` method in controller B gets called, I want to call my `appendToLog(String msg)` method from controller A.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please remember that this isn't a code writing service. You need to edit the question to include your code so far and to explain where you are getting stuck. If you don't know where to start, please identify the documentation/articles you have read so far and why they did not help. Thanks.

Comment: Consider using a shared model. One controller would update the model, the other controller would react to the update.

Comment: Another common method is to have a parent controller (probably the one that loads the `TabPane`), then pass this controller instance to all the tab controllers.